# Pictures in table won't resize

Tags: html, image, resize, html-table

I am working on a website right now and I've worked the following HTML code to display 3 pictures side by side:

```
<table ><tr>
<td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OePsoQN.png" alt="fivera"  height="283.5" width="504"  ></td>
<td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/PeZkl4t.png" alt="fivera"  height="283.5" width="504" ></td>
<td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fqvrtec.png" alt="fivera"  height="283.5" width="504" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It looks perfectly fine on my computer, but when I resize my browser size the pictures' size remain unchanged and it ruins the entire website by pretty much having a horizontal scroll bar show up.
I've been Googling about this issue for the past 20 minutes but no solution has worked for me.

Your suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The images will remain the same size no matter what size the browser window is. You have a static width and height property for each image established.

```
height="283.5" width="504"
```

One way to adjust the images along with the windows resize would be to use a javascript function to do the resizing.

```
<body onresize="ResizeFunction()">
```

A quick easy way would be to do the following:

```
<table ><tr>
<td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OePsoQN.png" alt="fivera" width="100%"></td>
<td><img src="https://i.imgur.com/PeZkl4t.png" alt="fivera" width="100%"></td>
<td><img src="http://i.imgur.com/fqvrtec.png" alt="fivera" width="100%"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

This would force the images to resize to 100% of the space the table gives them. Give it a try. The height will maintain the aspect ratio with the width automatically.

Comment: I used this exact code you gave me and its really tiny now. Please check it out at the bottom of this page: http://canvasbros.com/

Comment: I see that you have the table holding the images within a few DIVs. One of those DIVs could be limiting the size of the table itself, thus limiting the size of the images. Try placing a width on the table itself. <table width="90%">

Comment: Could you please suggest me how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would group these into a div element so you can manipulate them all at once. If your wanting high quality .css should be used.

say this div has a id of img:

```
<div id="img">
```

Then in .css do the following:

```
#img { max-width: 100%; }
```